# Would it make sense to store repeated error messages as constant variables in Solidity?

Tags: variables, optimization, solidity

I am currently developing a smart contract in which the same error message is repeated a lot of times in multiple require statements.

By storing the message in a **constant** variable and using such variable in all of the require commands (instead of repeating the actual string), would I optimize gas/memory usage? Or is that a bad idea (if so, why)?

**Example**

Before:

```
contract myContract{

  function myFunc() external {
    require( [CONDITION_A] , "Test failed");
    require( [CONDITION_B] , "Test failed");
    require( [CONDITION_C] , "Test failed");
    require( [CONDITION_D] , "Test failed");
    [ACTUAL_OPERATIONS]
  }

}
```

After:

```
contract myContract{

  string constant errMsg = "Test failed";

  function myFunc() external {
    require( [CONDITION_A] , errMsg );
    require( [CONDITION_B] , errMsg );
    require( [CONDITION_C] , errMsg );
    require( [CONDITION_D] , errMsg );
    [ACTUAL_OPERATIONS]
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In any case, error codes are more optimized: https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/

Answer (score 0):

The first one should be more gas optimized. Because accessing global variable would need more gas.

Here is a sample of option 1:

[image]

Here is a sample of option 2:

[image]

As you would see for the two code snippet with the similar functionality option 1 requires gas (21416) less than option 2 (22030).